# Axios API call speed less than Postman's

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I have API call and it is taking 0.5 seconds in postman whereas the same API call taking 10 seconds with axios. How should I increase this speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in the browser, you make 2 requests, unlike Postman. One is OPTIONS for check CORS and one is GET, POST, etc. Your API server returns a header when OPTIONS request which is `Access-Control-Max-Age`. `Access-Control-Max-Age` value stands for how long wait for the next OPTIONS request. May your API was not set an `Access-Control-Max-Age` header or set for too short therefore your browser always makes 2 requests. Needs to be more investigation here to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way for improve speed with Axios because postman is s/w and axios is package lib with different functionality and using your application to run it while postman run api directly thats why its faster than axios.

Answer (score 1):

The Postman isn't a browser so it will not worry about CORS and can send the POST without sending the OPTIONS, so only incurs the cost of the POST.
and your sever may take time to process the OPTIONS request and then the POST request so whether you are using axios or fetch even XHRHttpRequest it will take more time than postman